# How to make tesseract to give relevant results in the presence of noise?

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I am using tesseract 3.0.0 and I bumped into the following problem:

When there is something too small for tesseract to recognize it seems it's merged with
other fragments. As a result nothing relevant is returned.

The image below shows 3 cases. Only the rectangle with the dashed line is passed to tesseract. Over the rectangle is the result (V over T means new line).

The last case is the problem one. Is there someway to improve tesseract in situations like this?

[image]

Comment: you can make it similar to cases 1 and 2 by stretching the image a bit. For barcodes it should work.

Comment: This will also stretch the digits and at some point they might not be readable. Also this won't work in other cases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, Tesseract does not have proper image segmentation yet (or Document Analysis, as it is called in commertial OCR applications.) Typically, before OCR is done, image is get's split on separate areas that contain text, pictures, barcodes, lines and so on. Then you apply OCR only on text ares and don't face problems you have just described.

Earlier versions of Tesseract did not have that functionality at all, and Tesseract was supposed to be used as line recognizer only, or so called field-level recognizer, when you use it on small snippets of text cut from bigger image.

I did not followed throughly what was introduced in 3.0, probably it is already there partially, but obviously it does not work as expected, as you have just found out.

There is another opensource project - OCRopus, that aproached this problem exactly as I described - first Document Analisys (aka Segmentation) and only then OCR. Their earlier versions were actually using Tesseract for OCR after analisys step finished. But later they introduced their own OCR (which is still not very good) and moved Tesseract plugin support down in priorities list.

Here's what you actually can do to address your problem:

- If your images have very typical structure, you can try to do some dumb segmentation and cut text from the image yourself before passing it to Tesseract. However, if you expect to have wide variety of images to be supported, just forget it.
- You can ckeck OCRopus and see if their segmentation work for your images. If yes, then you can spend some time to make OCRopus + Tesseract work together.
- Well, if what you do is not just for fun and you value your time, I would recommend thinking about real OCR engine like ABBYY. You will get much higher accuracy of both segmentaiton and OCR out of the box, and professional customer support of course.

Disclaimer: I work for ABBYY

Comment: Thanks for the answer Andrey. In the release notes of V3.0.0 is written: "Added major new page layout analysis module", which is may be not so good yet. Another thing is that we can set the segmentation mode to say what the image represents - character, word, line or block of text. I was hoping, while using the 'block' segmentation mode, there is a way to make tesseract process them as different lines, just like the second case. About your proposals: unfortunately the structure of the images will vary, second I need it to be an engine/library and for now I have not yet given up on tesseract.